# Why is my VPN changing my ipv4 address but not my ipv6?

Tags: privacy, proxy

I'm looking for information on this but there's nothing out there. My VPN is working, it changes my IP address, but it only changes my ipv4 address. Google still knows where I am because it lists the ipv6 address instead. Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your IPv6 traffic is leaking. This is because most VPN networks are **not** compatible with IPv6.

To ensure you don’t have IPv6 traffic running outside the VPN tunnel :

> Online Service to Check IPv6 Support : http://ip6.nl/
>
> If it says No IPv6 connectivity, your IPv6 traffic isn’t leaking.

If it is leaking, consider disabling it in your operating system:

```
(google search) : disable ipv6 (your-operating-system)
```

- [How to disable IPv6 or its components in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/how-to-disable-ipv6-or-its-components-in-windows)
- [How to disable IPv6 or its components in OSX](http://help.unc.edu/help/how-do-i-disable-ipv6-on-mac-os-x/)